# How to click the checkbox using Selenium WebDriver and C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

What I'm trying to do is click on (or off) any of the checkboxes on my page.  As you can see from the HTML, each checkbox element would appear to have a unique identifier but when I try to click on it, I get an "Element not found" exception. I've tried all the standard locators (there's no iframe either) -- 
I can find the checkbox element, ok but just can't click on it.

Please view the following HTML:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label for="Url_option1">Option 1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <input type="checkbox" data-yesno-name="Url_option1" class="url-field-toggle">
            <span class="glyphicon clickable glyphicon-remove" id="toggle_undefined"></span>
            <input id="Url_url_option1" name="Url.url_option1" type="hidden" value="no"> &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label for="Url_option2">Option 2</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <input type="checkbox" data-yesno-name="Url_option2" class="url-field-toggle">
            <span class="glyphicon clickable glyphicon-remove" id="toggle_undefined"></span>
            <input id="Url_translation_c" name="Url.option2" type="hidden" value="no"> &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label for="Url_option3">Option 3</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <input type="checkbox" data-yesno-name="Url_option3" class="url-field-toggle">
            <span class="glyphicon clickable glyphicon-remove" id="toggle_undefined"></span>
            <input id="Url_option3" name="Url.option3" type="hidden" value="no"> &nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label for="Url_option4">Option 4</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <input type="checkbox" data-yesno-name="Url_option4" class="url-field-toggle">
            <span class="glyphicon clickable glyphicon-remove" id="toggle_undefined"></span>
            <input id="Url_option4" name="Url.option4" type="hidden" value="no"> &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label for="Url_option5">Option 5</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <input type="checkbox" data-yesno-name="Url_option5" class="url-field-toggle">
            <span class="glyphicon clickable glyphicon-remove" id="toggle_undefined"></span>
            <input id="Url_option5" name="Url.option5" type="hidden" value="no"> &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label for="Url_option6">Option 6</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <input type="checkbox" data-yesno-name="Url_option6" class="url-field-toggle">
            <span class="glyphicon clickable glyphicon-remove" id="toggle_undefined"></span>
            <input id="Url_option6" name="Url.option6" type="hidden" value="no"> &nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The only way I can click on any of the check box elements is by locating the following element:

```
<span class="glyphicon clickable glyphicon-remove" id="toggle_undefined"></span>
```

Using an XPath locator:

```
i.e //*[@id="toggle_undefined"]
```

The click event gets fired in this case but it will obviously only click on the first element (or checkbox in this case) on the page (I've over 20 checkboxes on the page).

Based on the HTML code above, let's say I wanted to enable the second checkbox element on row two. Here is the code for this checkbox element:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <label for="Url_option5">Option 5</label>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1">
    <input type="checkbox" data-yesno-name="Url_option5" class="url-field-toggle">
    <span class="glyphicon clickable glyphicon-remove" id="toggle_undefined"></span>
    <input id="Url_option5" name="Url.option5" type="hidden" value="no"> &nbsp;
</div>
```

Based on the info above I can only click the checkbox by finding and clicking on the following element:

```
<span class="glyphicon clickable glyphicon-remove" id="toggle_undefined"></span>
```

How am I supposed to create a unique XPath locator for this element that I could use to click on any of the checkboxes on my page?

Comment: Which corresponding checkbox do you want to interact with `Account Summary` or `Transactions`?

Comment: The `data-yesno-name="Url_Transaction_Out"` looks to be unique, have you tried that in a locator? What have you tried? I don't see any code.

Comment: I've updated the question.  Hopefully it's clearer now

Comment: @Banjaxx Why are you updating the question without trying out the well researched answers from the volunteers? Did you try out any of the answers? Can you let us know the results? If your requirement have changed feel free to raise a new question instead of editing/updating the existing question. For the time being I am reverting back the question to it's previous state.

Comment: @Banjaxx, BTW, your update does not make any sense.

Comment: It took me 20 minutes to update my question.  My update made more sense until it was reverted back by staff.  I'll ask a new question

Comment: I've rolled back the update OP made and smoothed out the wording and fixed indent. It's understandable now.

Comment: @JeffC Your rolling back of the question makes all the efforts behind constructing  the well researched (existing) answers invalid. Please act consciously and don't roll back simply to answer a completely different edited question.

Comment: @DebanjanB OP edited their question and added more detail. You misread the edited question and rolled it back adding more confusion. If you look at the original question and the current question... they are the same question, this one just has more detail. You further confused OP causing him to create yet another question which you dup'd to this one. If they are the same question, why did you roll it back here? If they weren't the same question, why did you dup it to this one? You seem to be the only one confused here.

Comment: @DebanjanB STOP rolling back the question. It's clearer and has more details in its current form and the accepted answer is based on the current question. See my last comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need to click the SPAN, e.g.

```
<span class="glyphicon clickable glyphicon-remove" id="toggle_undefined"></span>
```

and there's no unique identifiers/attributes on it, we'll have to locate the right one by using one of the surrounding elements.

Probably what I would use is to find the SPAN by the relative LABEL, e.g.

```
<label for="Url_option1">Option 1</label>
```

You can use an XPath like

```
//label[.='Option 3']//following::span[@id='toggle_undefined']
```

What this does is finds the LABEL that contains the desired string, 'Option 3', and then finds the first SPAN that follows with the ID 'toggle_undefined'.

If it were me, I would wrap this in a function and pass in the option name I was looking to click, e.g.

```
public void Toggle(string optionName)
{
    Driver.Value.FindElement(By.XPath($"//label[.='{optionName}']//following::span[@id='toggle_undefined']")).Click();
}
```

and call it like

```
Toggle("Option 3");
```

Comment: A slight modification to the Xpath and this worked perfectly!  I needed to use this: "FindElement(By.XPath("//label[@for='option1']//following::span[@id='toggle_undefined']"));"Thank you and sorry for any trouble :)

Comment: Good answer, Jeff!

Answer (score 1):

To get input with type checkbox just use css selector below.

Element:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-yesno-name="Url_Transaction_Out" class="url-field-toggle" style="" checked="checked"><span class="glyphicon clickable glyphicon-ok" id="toggle_undefined">
```

Css Selector:

```
input[data-yesno-name='Url_Transaction_Out']
```

Code:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[data-yesno-name='Url_Transaction_Out']")).Click();
```

To check and select:

```
IWebElement checkbox = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[data-yesno-name='Url_Transaction_Out']"));
if(!checkbox.IsSelected())
{
    checkbox.Click();
}
```

Comment: I've updated the question.  Hopefully it's clearer now

Answer (score 1):

Use the following CSS Selector for that:

```
.url-field-toggle[data-yesno-name='Url_Transaction_Out']
```

Code is:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("url-field-toggle[data-yesno-name='Url_Transaction_Out']")).Click();
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: I've updated the question.  Hopefully it's clearer now

Answer (score 1):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to invoke `click()` on the desired *checkbox* you can use either of the following solutions:

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("label[for=Url_Transaction_Out]")).Click();
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//label[@for='Url_Transaction_Out']")).Click();
  ```

Comment: I've updated the question.  Hopefully it's clearer now

Comment: None of the answers worked because my question didn't contain enough information to provide an accurate answer.  Thank you for trying to help.  I'm not going to mark any of the answers down because it wouldn't be fair.  The answer provided below by jeffc is what I was looking for